# Url with = sign and get value from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I'm trying to get `multiple` value from URL. But i don't know how `Url` is getting multiple `=` sign. That is why i am unable to get it using the `querystring`. So i am accessing the full URL and trying to get the value from it but i am unable to remove % sign from values.
Here is my code.

```
string fullUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
string str = fullUrl.Substring(fullUrl.LastIndexOf("Amount"));
```

**Here fullUrl has the value as below:-**

> fullUrl =
>   "http://localhost:10372/Customer/Success.aspx?URL=Amount=10&Name=Shami%20%20Sheikh&EmailOfPayer=ansitshami911@gmail.com&bussness=61339393592016_Preevet&CompanyName=Shami%20Sheikh&PaymentDate=07/03/2018%2015:50:48&SecuritiesandComplianceFee=0.47&BackmyUri=http://localhost:11181/Payment.aspx&phone=1234567891&Cardnumber=973638353835&Country=198&St=354&Other=&city=Delhi&Address=Delhi&ZipCode=201301&EmailOfReceiver=ansitshami911@gmail.com&Planrateforaccount=40&Planrateforcard=60&Planrateforcheck=2018&PlanYear=2018"

str variable has the value as below

> str =
>   Amount=10&Name=Shami%20%20Sheikh&EmailOfPayer=ansitshami911@gmail.com&bussness=61339393592016_Preevet&CompanyName=Shami%20Sheikh&PaymentDate=07/03/2018%2015:50:48&SecuritiesandComplianceFee=0.47&BackmyUri=http://localhost:11181/Payment.aspx&phone=1234567891&Cardnumber=973638353835&Country=198&St=354&Other=&city=Delhi&Address=Delhi&ZipCode=201301&EmailOfReceiver=ansitshami911@gmail.com&Planrateforaccount=40&Planrateforcard=60&Planrateforcheck=2018&PlanYear=2018

**Here is my code to get the value from `URL` :-**

```
 string s = str;
 String[] arr = s.Split('&');
   var Namearr = from word in arr
                              where word.StartsWith("Name")
                              select word;
                foreach (var item1 in Namearr)
                {
                    string str1 = item1.ToString();
                    string[] strArr = str1.Split('=');
                    string Name = strArr[1];
                }
```

> But the value assigned in variable is `Name` = "Shami%20%20Sheikh"

Now when i am trying to get the value of `Name` it returns the value with `%` sign .

How can i get the actual value from `URl`?

Comment: Yes using server.urldecode it works fine. Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using server.UrlDecode it works fine.

> string fullUrl = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());

Answer (score 3):

You can get query string values that are already processed using:

```
Request.QueryString["Name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the following code you will get the all the queryString parameters from where you can find your element queryString parameter and it's value.

```
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys) {
    Response.Write("Key: " + key + " Value: " + Request.QueryString[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(Name)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank for your time . And the problem has been solved by using Server.UrlDecode